# Getting the Class attribute works in IE9 but not IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8

I have this internal application that I made.  It works fine in IE9 (and all the other browsers) but some of the internal users are still on IE8.

The line causing the problem is:

```
var thisClass = $thisElement.attributes.class.value;
```

I get the error message is "SCRIPT1010: Expected identifier" and the marker is just before the c in class.

Here is the code:

```
$(document).on('click', function(){ 
var $this = $(this);
var $thisElement = $this.context.activeElement;
if ($thisElement != null && $thisElement.attributes.type != null && $thisElement.attributes.type.value == "checkbox"   ){
        var thisClass = $thisElement.attributes.class.value;
        var thisValue = $thisElement.value;
        if (thisValue == "All"){
            if($thisElement.checked){
                $('input[class="'+thisClass+'"]').each(function(i){
                        var checkboxValue = $(this).val();
                        $("#"+thisClass+checkboxValue).prop('checked',true);
                 });

            }else {             
                $('input[class="'+thisClass+'"]').each(function(i){
                    var checkboxValue = $(this).val();
                    $("#"+thisClass+checkboxValue).prop('checked',false);
                });                 
            }               
        }else // since the val is not = all we want to uncheck the all box if any of the bottom boxes is unchecked
        if (!$thisElement.checked){                 
                $("#"+thisClass+"All").prop('checked',false);
        }
        cnse.checkTheCheckboxes();
    }else{
        return;
    };// end if it is a checkbox
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking to get the class of an element in HTML, you want to use the `className` attribute on the element itself:

```
var thisClass = $thisElement.className;
```

Comment: This works for both IE8 and IE9.  Interestingly the code above works fine in IE9. Thanks

Comment: @user1368301 Jonathan's answer explains why you see a difference between the browsers. Glad things are working for you!

Answer (score 3):

ECMAScript 3-based engines, like that in IE8, don't allow reserved words to be used as identifiers with dot notation. For them, you'll need to quote `class` using [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators#Bracket_notation):

```
var thisClass = $thisElement.attributes["class"].value;
```

ECMAScript 5 changed a few use cases to allow using [Identifier Names rather than just Identifiers](http://es5.github.io/#x7.6), including with [dot notation](http://es5.github.io/#x11.2.1). Which is why it works in IE9.

You can also simply use the [`className` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.className), as [Marc suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18665898), as that isn't a reserved word.